# Adobe AIR HTML/JS application with javascript scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, air, scrollbar

I would like to know if it is possible to have custom Javascript scrollbars in an Adobe AIR application. The AIR application is HTML/JS based. I want to have custom scrollbars for some divs and iFrames.
I've tried many jQuery plugins (antiscroll, lionbars, etc) but nothing worked. I can only style the native AIR scrollbars with CSS.

So, does Adobe AIR support javascript based scrollbars for HTML blocks / iFrames?

Answer (score 2):

First, answer to your question:

Yes, Adobe AIR support javascript based scrollbars for HTML blocks/iFrames.

And more to this answer:
This is very old question but my answer would help someone. As there is not much documentation available for Adobe AIR.
Do something in the Javascript, do not use latest jQuery plugin. It will work definitely. 
Go through the supported list of elements that supports the Adobe AIR.

WebKit features not supported in AIR

Adobe AIR 1.0 and later

```
AIR does not support the following features available in WebKit or Safari 4:
```

- Cross-domain messaging via window.postMessage (AIR provides its own cross-domain communication APIs)
- CSS variables
- Web Open Font Format (WOFF) and SVG fonts.
- HTML video and audio tags
- Media device queries
- Offline application cache
- Printing (AIR provides its own PrintJob API)
- Spelling and grammar checkers
- SVG
- WAI-ARIA
- WebSockets (AIR provides its own socket APIs)
- Web workers
- WebKit SQL API (AIR provides its own API)
- WebKit geolocation API (AIR provides its own geolocation API on supported devices)
- WebKit multi-file upload API
- WebKit touch events (AIR provides its own touch events)
- Wireless Markup Language (WML)
  The following lists contain specific JavaScript APIs, HTML elements, and CSS properties and values that AIR does not support:

  Unsupported JavaScript Window object members:

  - applicationCache()
  - console
  - openDatabase()
  - postMessage()
  - document.print()
    Unsupported HTML tags:
  - audio
  - video
  - Unsupported HTML attributes:
  - aria-*
  - draggable
  - formnovalidate
  - list
  - novalidate
  - onbeforeload
  - onhashchange
  - onorientationchange
  - onpagehide
  - onpageshow
  - onpopstate
  - ontouchstart
  - ontouchmove
  - ontouchend
  - ontouchcancel
  - onwebkitbeginfullscreen
  - onwebkitendfullscreen
  - pattern
  - required
  - sandbox
    Unsupported JavaScript events:
  - beforeload
  - hashchange
  - orientationchange
  - pagehide
  - pageshow
  - popstate
  - touchstart
  - touchmove
  - touchend
  - touchcancel
  - webkitbeginfullscreen
  - webkitendfullscreen
    Unsupported CSS properties:
  - background-clip
  - background-origin (use -webkit-background-origin)
  - background-repeat-x
  - background-repeat-y
  - background-size (use -webkit-background-size)
  - border-bottom-left-radius
  - border-bottom-right-radius
  - border-radius
  - border-top-left-radius
  - border-top-right-radius
  - text-rendering
  - -webkit-animation-play-state
  - -webkit-background-clip
  - -webkit-color-correction
  - -webkit-font-smoothing
    Unsupported CSS values:
  - appearance property values:
  - media-volume-slider-container
  - media-volume-slider
  - media-volume-sliderthumb
  - outer-spin-button
  - border-box (background-clip and background-origin)
  - contain (background-size)
  - content-box (background-clip and background-origin)
  - cover (background-size)
  - list property values:
  - afar
  - amharic
  - amharic-abegede
  - cjk-earthly-branch
  - cjk-heavenly-stem
  - ethiopic
  - ethiopic-abegede
  - ethiopic-abegede-am-et
  - ethiopic-abegede-gez
  - ethiopic-abegede-ti-er
  - ethiopic-abegede-ti-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-aa-er
  - ethiopic-halehame-aa-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-am-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-gez
  - ethiopic-halehame-om-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-sid-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-so-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-ti-er
  - ethiopic-halehame-ti-et
  - ethiopic-halehame-tig
  - hangul
  - hangul-consonant
  - lower-norwegian
  - oromo
  - sidama
  - somali
  - tigre
  - tigrinya-er
  - tigrinya-er-abegede
  - tigrinya-et
  - tigrinya-et-abegede
  - upper-greek
  - upper-norwegian
  - -wap-marquee (display property)

Source:[Adobe Air Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-67c0013e126afbe6c4d-8000.html)